# Putting a Battleship' position into an array [java]

Tags: java, arrays

I've been having this slight issue with my Battleship program. Within my tester I have created a boat object [a destroyer (holds 2 spots)that is vertical with the starting position of pos1] as well as some testers:

```
public class BoatTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Position pos1 = new Position(4, 5);
        Position pos2 = new Position(3, 5);
        Boat ship1 = new Boat("Destroyer", pos1, "vertical");

        //Hits the starting position as it is a definite hit
        System.out.println("Hitting...");
        ship1.hit(pos1);

        System.out.println("Starting Position Hit? " + ship1.isHit(pos1)); //returns true   

        System.out.println("Ship Sunk? " + ship1.sunk(pos2)); //false, as the destroy has 2 spots
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Hitting Other Position(s)...");

        //This doesn't work
        ship1.onBoat(pos2);

}}
```

In my actual boat class(which has the code to run all this), the constructor takes the type of boat it is, the starting position (position one) and the orientation, then it fills an array with Position objects to the correct amount of spots.

*Note that the Position obj, just has methods to give the x and y positions of the boat.

**Also note that the code will set the array position [0] as the starting position (position one) and generate from there on.

```
public class Boat {
    private String name;
    private Position location;
    private String orientation;

    private Position[] boat;

    public Boat(String ship, Position p, String orien){
        name = ship;
        location = p;
        orientation = orien;
        boat = new Position[size()];
        boat[0] = p;
        if(orientation.equals("Vertical"))  {
            for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
                hold = new Position((location.rowIndex() + i), location.columnIndex());
                boat[i] =  hold;
            }
        }//Just the flipped of vertical 
        else if(orientation.equals("Horizontal"))   {
            for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
                hold = new Position(location.rowIndex(), (location.columnIndex() + i));
                boat[i] =  hold;
            }
        }

    }
```

Now in this Boat class, when I call another method (not included) to see if the second position that I passed in from the tester is there (it's suppose to be there) the program crashes with an error saying that the array is out of bounds. What I don't understand is why there is no second position to the array, as it seems like my constructor isn't making the second Position obj.

*Note I tried to follow etiquette and keep this as concise as possible, and the full code can be found here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16Hp7Uu_-UZE3PwfQPurNIxl7CAzH8t2nEhUyB6Te_qc/edit?usp=sharing

**Note 2, I'm a student, and may not know the very intricate workings of java, so please explain like I'm five.

Edit 1: My bad, here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Boat.onBoat(Boat.java:80)
    at BoatTester.main(BoatTester.java:15)
```

The one at Boat.onBoat is just my test of the boat[1] (second position) of the array, which shows there being nothing there.

Edit 2: Here's the onBoat exception to clarify.

```
public boolean onBoat(Position spot){
        //Throws and exception here when I check the second index of the array
        System.out.println(boat[1].rowIndex()); //Specifically line 80
        System.out.println(boat[1].columnIndex());
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error and identify the line of the code it refers to.

Comment: It would be simpler if you post the exception.

Comment: You need to check code on line 80 of Boat.java class in the `onBoat` method. You still haven't posted that part.

Comment: Can you post line 80, please?

Comment: I probably should have said check instead of test.

Comment: You may wish to learn some debugging techniques: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, this is just one of those cases of me being dumb. I used .equals("Vertical") instead of .equalsIgnoreCase("Vertical") and in the tester class I had it as lower case "vertical" so it gave me an error. I suck.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
            hold = new Position((location.rowIndex() + i), location.columnIndex());
            boat[i] =  hold;
        }
    }//Just the flipped of vertical 
    else if(orientation.equals("Horizontal"))   {
        for(int i = 1; i < size(); i++) {
            hold = new Position(location.rowIndex(), (location.columnIndex() + i));
            boat[i] =  hold;
        }
```

Well it can just be that your for loop does only one loop for i = 1 because battleship's size is 2.

Comment: I had already added the boat[0] = p; earlier on for the first position though, to have the first position be the original pos1. So the boat[1] (second position in the array) would be one more than the original pos1, but it doesn't seem to be adding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is probably your problem.  You should use name.equals("Destroyer");

```
public int size(){
    if(name == "Aircraft Carrier"){
        return 5;
    }if(name == "Battleship"){
        return 4;
    }if(name == "Cruiser"){
        return 3;
    }if(name == "Destroyer"){
        return 2;
    }else{
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Plus, your size function probably ends with return 1;.  I assumed old code.

Comment: You would always return three from this function.  However you current size() is probably different.

Comment: This wasn't it, but it did lead me to finding my actual error. Thank you very much!

Comment: I should have caught that.